# How to invoke a function when changing position?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to invoke a function everytime the position of a `position2D` node is changed

I tried to override the setter as given in the [docs](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node2d.html#class-node2d-property-position) like this:

```
extends Position2D
tool

func set_position(value):
    print("changed position ",value)
    self.position=value;
```

what am I missing here? is there a way to achieve what I'm trying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `set_position` is not virtual. You are not overriding it. At best you are hiding it.

If you want to follow that approach, intercept the property instead, using [`_set`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-set) (Notice that the documentation mentions that `_set` is virtual). The idea is that we are going to take the attempt to set `position`, do whatever we want to do when it is set, and then let it continue normally.

```
func _set(property:String, value) -> bool:
    if property == "position":
        print("changed position ",value)

    return false
```

And you should see that when you modify the `position` in the inspector panel, you get the message.

---

I suspect that is not enough for you. In particular the above solution does not detect when the `position` changes because you drag the `Position2D` in the editor.

This is becase when you move the `Position2D` in the editor, Godot is not setting the `position` property. Instead it is (after digging in the source code) calling the undocumented method `_edit_set_position`… Which you can also call from GDScript! Anyway, the point is we cannot intercept it (and we cannot override it. Yes, I tried).

---

Instead we are going to use [`_notification`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-notification). We are looking for `NOTIFICATION_TRANSFORM_CHANGED`, but to get that notification we need to enable it with `set_notify_transform`. The code looks like this:

```
tool
extends Position2D

func _enter_tree() -> void:
    set_notify_transform(true)

func _notification(what: int) -> void:
    if what == NOTIFICATION_TRANSFORM_CHANGED:
        print("changed position", position)
```

With this approach you will also be able to react to when the user moves the `Position2D` in the editor by dragging it around or with the keyboard directional keys. Which are the cases where Godot uses `_edit_set_position`. Or any other means that we could not intercept with the initial approach.

You can use this approach if you need to do something every time the `Node2D` moves, but it does not move very often.

*By the way, this also works for 3D.*